# Assembling a sparse matrix for the PaStiX solver

Tags: sparse-matrix, libraries

I've been searching the whole afternoon for some documentation or code sample showing how to assemble a sparse matrix of a problem to be solved with PaStiX, but couldn't find any. The relevant module seems to be SPM, but its documentation is missing in the [manual](https://solverstack.gitlabpages.inria.fr/pastix/group__spm__dev__driver.html). Besides, the [official examples](https://solverstack.gitlabpages.inria.fr/pastix/group__pastix__examples.html) load a matrix from disk, rather than assembling it.

What I'm looking for is an API in SPM so that I can tell it to start with an all-zeroes matrix, and then add non-zero items to the appropriate ij positions.

The problem I wish to solve is about structural analysis, so I have the stiffness matrix for each member, and I know the ij position in the global matrix where each element from a member should be assembled into. But I just cannot find the API for doing so.

What's the expected way for doing this in PaStiX?

Comment: Not a proper answer, but a follow-up for saying that after a day of search, I found that the PETSc driver for PaStiX (https://github.com/petsc/petsc/blob/main/src/mat/impls/aij/mpi/pastix/pastix.c) provides a good reference, showing how to encode a matrix as CSC for PaStiX. It also says that in symmetric matrices, PaStiX just needs half of the matrix defined (which is greatly welcome, but it's not mentioned in any documentation AFAIK). Also, the SPM library has some examples (https://solverstack.gitlabpages.inria.fr/spm/group__examples__c.html) that can help. But no detailed documentation.